# autoprefixerでgridを有効にしているのにIE11でレイアウトが崩れる

Tags: css, gulp, sass

Gulpでautoprefixerを用いていて、コンパイル後のcssには-ms-のベンダープレフィックスは追加されているのですが、IE11だとレイアウトが崩れてしまいます。

崩れるというよりも具体的にはレイアウトが一つだけになってしまいます。

**HTML**

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="item">
    テスト
    </div>
    <div class="item">
    テスト
    </div>
    <div class="item">
    テスト
    </div>
    <div class="item">
    テスト 
    </div>
    <div class="item">
    テスト
    </div>
</div
```

**gulpfile.js**

```
autoprefixer({
 grid: true,
 browsers: ["ie >= 11"]
})
```

**CSS**

```
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 1em;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Autoprefixer の grid オプションの `true` は、 `no-autoplace` の別名です。しかし、 `true` という表記は**廃止予定**になっているため、今後 Autoprefixer を導入する場合、使用するべきではありません。

> ### [Options](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer#options)
>
> Function `autoprefixer(options)` returns a new PostCSS plugin. See [PostCSS API] for plugin usage documentation.
>
> - `grid` (false|"autoplace"|"no-autoplace"): should Autoprefixer   add IE 10-11 prefixes for Grid Layout properties?
>
>   - `"no-autoplace"`: enable Autoprefixer grid translations but *exclude* autoplacement support. You can also use `/* autoprefixer grid: no-autoplace */` in your CSS. (**alias for the deprecated `true` value**)

また、グリッドの自動配置を行なうにもかかわらず、 grid オプションに `no-autoplace` と同等の役割を持つ `true` を設定することは不適切です。そのため、今回 grid オプションに設定するべき値は `autoplace` です。

```
autoprefixer({
  grid: "autoplace",
  browsers: ["ie >= 11"]
})
```

---

次に、グリッドの自動配置は `grid-template-rows` プロパティ、 `grid-template-columns` プロパティの**両方が設定されていなければ動作しません**。

> ### [Grid Autoplacement support in IE](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer#grid-autoplacement-support-in-ie)
>
> If the `grid` option is set to `"autoplace"`, limited autoplacement support is added to Autoprefixers grid translations. You can also use the `/* autoprefixer grid: autoplace */` control comment to enable autoplacement
>
> Autoprefixer will only autoplace grid cells if both `grid-template-rows` and `grid-template-columns` has been set. If `grid-template` or `grid-template-areas` has been set, Autoprefixer will use area based cell placement instead.
>
> Autoprefixer supports autoplacement by using `nth-child` CSS selectors. It creates [number of columns] x [number of rows] `nth-child` selectors. For this reason Autoplacement is only supported within the explicit grid.

`grid-template` プロパティ、もしくは `grid-template-areas` プロパティなどを使用するのでなければ、前述した 2 つのプロパティを設定してください。

```
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
  grid-gap: 1em;
}
```